# Not enough argument for format string while importing csv into MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
Full Traceback:
 File "./csvimportdb.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO newsletter_subscriber(id, name, email ) VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")''', row)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='english', passwd='english', db='english_mez')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('final.csv'))
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO newsletter_subscriber(id, name, email )' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', row[0], row[1], row[2])
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

I need to pass `row, row, row` to make it right but can't do that. How to fix?

**Edit**: Printing row gives:

```
['6630\tCarmen Rocche\trocchecarmen@gmail.com\t\t\t\t\t']
['6631\tSuhasini\tkkalva14@hotmail.com\t\t\t\t\t']
['6632\tAmarjeet \tsweetylamba@gmail.com\t\t\t\t\t']
['6633\tFazali Hadi\tshewasb@yahoo.com\t\t\t\t\t']
['6634\tVishaka Samarakone\tshirashi.vishaka@gmail.com\t\t\t\t\t']
['6635\tLoemongga\tloemongga@yahoo.com\t\t\t\t\t']
```

Comment: can i know the contents of `final.csv`

Comment: i updated the answer. you need `data=row[0].split('\t')` because it is not comma seperated, rather it is tab seperated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row in csv_data:
    data=row[0].split('\t')
    if len(data) < 4: continue
    query="""insert into newsletter_subscriber (id, name, email) values 
      (%d, '%s', '%s')""" %(int(data[0]), data[1], data[2])
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Already tried it, list index out of range error. I am updating question with csv content.

Comment: Nope,  `cursor.execute("insert into newsletter_subscriber(id, name, email) values (?, ?, ?)", (data[0], data[1], data[2]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159,` in execute`
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: @user2032220 try `(int(data[0]), data[1], data[2]))`

Comment: @user2032220 i updated answer. i don't know what is the problem sorry :(

Comment: tried that which results in `query="""insert into newsletter_subscriber(id, name, email) values(%d, '%s', '%s')""" %(int(data[0]), data[1], data[2])
IndexError: list index out of range`
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41932/discussion-between-suhail-and-user2032220)